# iPhone HTTP live streaming

Tags: iphone, http, streaming, live

Have been researching the best way to tap into a live stream already being broadcast by S4C here -

mms://media7.unique-media.com/s4c_uk_live
(will open in something like quicktime)

Need to know best practices to get this streamed to iPhone in development.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to take a look [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) document for the full outline of the specs needed to do live iPhone streaming. Basically, MMS isn't going to work and you will need to implement the adaptive HTTP protocols/segments required by the iPhone.